# Bootstrap 4 modals doesn't work properly after $.get

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have several modals in my application and they seem to work nicelly except the ones that I dinamically call via $.Get.

The content is loaded but the buttons doesn't work. I can't use the cancel button, the close button and the submit button, but I can submit the form if i press Enter.

This is the code for the ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal', function(event) {
    var pageName = $(this).attr('pageName');
    $.get(pageName, function(data) {
        let result = $(data).find('#copy-modal');
        $('#generic-modal').html(result);
    });
    $("#generic-modal").modal('show');
});
```

This is the code of the button or link that triggers the event:

```
<button type='button' name="uid" id="openCompany" pageName="rt_users/empresas/{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-info open-modal"> |
    <i class="material-icons">business</i>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
</button>
```

And this is the generic modal code:

```
<div id="generic-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body"></div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Why are you completely replacing one modal for another? Shouldn't you just be putting the content inside your modal-body instead of replacing the entire modal?

Comment: That's correct! Thanks for the comment, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're replacing the entire modal into another one the DOM is not the same as when the function started.

You have two options, you can either just change the content of your modal (that normally is done in this case) or you need to refresh your DOM object before doing your show function.

To refresh the DOM object you might need some event delegation.

My advise would be to just use option one and replace this:

```
 $('#generic-modal').html(result);
```

With this:

```
 $('#generic-modal .modal-body').html(result);
```